# The conversion from line "X" to boolean is invalid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is my code:

```vb
Private Sub Kuiper_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData + "\KuiperStudio\settings\theme.txt" Then
            Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData + "\KuiperStudio\settings\theme.txt"
            If fileReader = "1" Then
                darkGrayTheme()
            ElseIf fileReader = "2" Then
                blackBlueTheme()
            ElseIf fileReader = "3" Then
                whiteBlueTheme()
            ElseIf fileReader = "4" Then

            Else
                darkGrayTheme()
            End If
        Else
        End If
    End Sub
```

The path of program files and it is not working, I tried to change it with my documents but it's still not working.

The error is:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'The conversion from line "C:\Users\Jelly Miner\AppData\Roa" to boolean is invalid.'

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write: `If File.Exist(My.Computer.FileSystem...) Then [...]`. Assign that path to a local variable, so you can verify whether that path actually points to where you think it should.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(String file)` method. You only provided a path in your If statement which is treated like a boolean expression. Thus the error.

Comment: Jimi and KevinMueller i forgot it, i wanted to write "if file exist". Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert the if statements into a switch case and see if that clarifies what you're after.

```
   Private Sub Kuiper_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData + "\KuiperStudio\settings\theme.txt" Then
            Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData + "\KuiperStudio\settings\theme.txt"
            Select Case fileReader
                Case "1"
                    darkGrayTheme()
                Case "2"
                    blackBlueTheme()
                Case "3"
                    whiteBlueTheme()
                Case "4"
                    redTheme()
                Case Else
                     redTheme()
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To me the first If does nothing, please verify it; what are you trying to get with this code?
Lucius